# What does Message.fetch() actually do in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

According to the [`Message#fetch()` docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetch), this function simply fetches the message it was called on. However, I'm not sure in which circumstance it would ever make sense to use this function.

[image: Docs]

According to the screenshot above, this method returns `Promise<Message>`. I'm confused, because why would you need to fetch a message you already have access to? For example:

```js
// let's say somebody sent the message `hello`

client.on('message', (message) => {
  console.log(message.content) // this would return `hello`
  message.fetch((message) => console.log(message.content)) // this would also return `hello`; it's the same object
```

So, what's the point of it? If you didn't have access to the message, you wouldn't be able to use `Message.fetch()` anyways.

And I'd ask the same question for [`Channel#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=fetch), [`ClientUser#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=fetch), [`Guild#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetch), [`GuildMember#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch), [`GuildPreview#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildPreview?scrollTo=fetch), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we dive into the source of the `Message` class and look for the `fetch` method, we see something like this:

```
/**
 * Fetch this message.
 * @param {boolean} [force=false] Whether to skip the cache check and request the API
 * @returns {Promise<Message>}
*/
fetch(force = false) {
  return this.channel.messages.fetch(this.id, true, force);
}
```

The `fetch()` method in this cases, retreives the last message posted in the channel. If you invoke this method and log the output, you see that it fetches the message you have posted. It simply returns asynchronous message object. `Promise<Message>`.

So let's say you post this message `Hello, i'm a message.` and invoke and log the `.fetch()` method, you see in the console the message object and content `Hello, i'm a message.`. All this does is fetching the message posted in the channel. Same goes for `channel#fetch`, `ClientUser#fetch`.

All it does is using the cache to fetch a channel, user, guild, message. The `force` argument is to receive the realtime data.

The `force` flag is used if you want to skip the cached message and want to do the API request.

If you wish to fetch all messages or a few messages, you can use the `MessageManager` class:

```
message.channel.messages.fetch('Message ID');
```

or

```
message.channel.messages.fetch({
    limit: 5, // Amount of messages to be fetched in the channel
    before: "Snowflake (ID from message to be fetched)",
    after: "Snowflake (ID from message to be fetched)",
});
```

More on this: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions

Comment: I think I understand why it works, but I'm wondering in what situation it would make sense to call the function.

Comment: @Lioness100 To not make your bot doing API requests on every message being posted. So instead use this method to retrieve the cached messages object. It's a bit unclear I agree, since the docs doesn't specify why and how you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

The point of this fetch command is because there are many situations where your bot does not have messages in cache to access. The most basic example is 1. During development you are are editing code and restarting the bot. Now those messages are lost and the bot doesn't have full access to them.

2. Your running program loses internet connection - enjoy your limited access and errors.
3. Cached messages are limited to 100 / channel. If you want access to earlier messages you must fetch. A common example is when the bot is asked to delete messages from a channel.
4. In our some of our servers the messages can exceed the cache amount within a minute. Specific messages / commands need to be fetched to auto-delete after x minutes.